# Missing partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partition-recovery

I have a 80gb hdd on my computer and has a partition : C:/ and D:/

I experienced having a trouble on boot start up : BOOTMGR MISSING pres CTRL ALT DEL to restart.I tried to fix the cable connections or any loosed wires but the same thing happened so I decided to re-format my D:/ which is the logical drive because C:/ "the system" contains all my backup files and it worked.

But the problem is: after I finished installing the OS I don't see the partition anymore The OS were in Local Disk(C:)37.1gb but I don't see Local Disk(D:). How will I recover my backup files and how will I do that?Where is my other partition?

Comment: You can paste a link to the image, someone with more rep will embed it inline for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a screenshot of Disk Management in Device Manager? Start -> right-click Computer -> Manage -> Disk Management. This will show all partitions on your disk.

The most likely answer is that you actually formatted your entire disk when reinstalling your OS, so both partitions are unrecoverable.

For the record, the original error sounds very much like a corrupt bootloader, which can be repaired with no need to reinstall using Windows' Startup Repair functionality on your Windows 7 install DVD.

Comment: I dont have 10 rep to post image but I can see the partition but it doesn't have a letter on it

Comment: Can you assign the partition a drive letter? In Disk Management, right-click on the partition and click "Change Drive Letter and Paths".

Comment: @NEWBIE You can upload a screenshot elsewhere (there are numerous image and photo sharing sites around) and include a link, and someone with enough rep will edit it into your question.

Comment: @NEWBIE What exactly fixed your problem? Note that you can add a self-answer below and accept it if the existing answer doesn't provide the solution. The question and answer will be *much* more useful for future visitors if there is an answer which actually solved the problem described.